# nsis - load plugin dll

Tags: dll, plugins, installation, nsis

I maked ASetup.exe file. 
The structure of the directory is shown below.

- /plugins
- /output
- ASetup.nsi

I added `!addplugindir ".\plugins"` in the ASetup.nsi file to use the plugin I created(B.dll).
The B.dll file will generate a .txt file when run the setup file.

On my local pc, the .txt file is created normally.

However, when I run setup file in vm, .txt file is not created.

I think the plugin (B.dll) file is not working properly.

Do I have to add another command instead of `!addplugindir`?

Comment: Not sure if this was your case, but I was using the ANSI version of the plugin, instead of the Unicode one

Answer (score 1):

`!addplugindir` is a compile-time command and just adds the specified directory to the list of directories searched by MakeNSIS when you execute a plug-in command.

Assuming

```
Section
!addplugindir ".\plugins"
B::MyPluginFunction
SectionEnd
```

compiles correctly then the issue is not with NSIS, you have to debug `MyPluginFunction` to figure out why it fails on other systems.

Perhaps `CreateFile` fails if the file does not exist? Invalid file path?